# Sharepoint alers email deletion from alerts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have given a list of emails on a sharepoint list that send out alers for the list whenever there is a change.

Now I face a problem to see who is on the list as I have to take away some addresses from it.

The address are from outside our domain so they are not listes in the System Administration/ User alerts.

How can I see the list or edit the list of email addresses.?

Comment: Please ask SharePoint specific questions in [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) community. This question does not belong here

Comment: oh okok.. I dint know there was one so I wrote it here.! Thank you any ways